# Twitter Bootstrap Image Gallery: how to change the loading path

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I installed Bootstrap Image Gallery in my Vendor folder as directed. Everything is working except I'm getting a JavaScript error:http://domain.com/img/loading.gif 404 (Not Found).

The path is set by Bootstrap Image Gallery JS file and I need to know how to change /img to my /images folder instead where the image is located. I see that around line:144 there's a loading function but I'm not familiar with JavaScript enough to know how to tweak that.

Here's the file:
https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the loading image is only defined in the CSS - [Line 70 of bootstrap-image-gallery.css](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/blob/master/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.css#L70). Change the path there and you should be good to go. (If you're using the minified file a search/replace for `img` to `image` should work).

Comment: That was extremely easy, I completely thought it would be more difficult so it made me forget about the css file. Thanks again for pointing it out.